# Naive bayes algorithm using php

Tags: php, naivebayes

I just need the help for implementing Naive Bayes Text Classification Algorithm in php to just test my Data Set for research purposes

Comment: why do u want to use PHP? There are Naive Bayes functions available in matlab or R programming. You will easily get the code in these language. Implementation in php will require more efforts and more lines of code.

Comment: we implemented in java,but we want implement this algorithm  in php .could you please help me to convert these code in to php. im new to php coding